# Saving date on parse server in android

Tags: android, date, parse-platform

I am working on Android application in which I want to save my date on parse server. I am getting date from server, but I can't be able to save it on server. I have used date picker which is I used to get Date from user and then I parse the format and "put" it in Parse Object. But it is not working.

My date coming from server is:

```
Date dobTxt = object.getDate("dateOfBirth");// Used to get Date Object from server
//Sun Jul 01 13:19:00 GMT+04:00 1990


String name = nameEditText.getText().toString();
String mobileNumber = mobileNumberEditText.getText().toString();
String occupation = occupationEditText.getText().toString();

ParseObject dataObject = new ParseObject();
dataObject.put("name", name);
dataObject.put("mobilenumber", mobileNumber);
dataObject.put("occupation", occupation);
dataObject.put("dateofBirth", date);
dataObject.saveInBackground();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a work around for this condition -

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("YourClassName", function(request, response) {
   request.object.set("yourDateField", new Date());
   response.success();
});
```

Here "yourDateField" is your date object.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi. i am facing same issue but my problem is little but diff

Comment: What problem you are facing, please specify.